# Change email address from Wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with front end login, it has the password recovery link which works fine.

The problem I have is that the password reset email that the user gets is saying it's from:

`WordPress <wordpress@domain.com>`

Is there a way I can change this? Possibly remove the word wordpress and/or change the actual email address it's from?

Comment: i think you can change this in wordpress general setting

Comment: @Pramod That doesn't actually change where the emails come from. It's currently set to my email address and that doesn't appear anywhere in the password reset email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this data in the wp-admin panel, General tab. Change the email adress and the domain name.

It should works.

If it's not working, consider using the [Send From](http://wordpress.org/plugins/send-from/) plugin or add some filter to `'wp_mail_from'`  like

```
function use_my_email(){
  return 'email@domain.com';
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'just_use_my_email' );
```

and `'wp_mail_from_name'`

```
function use_my_name(){
  return 'My Real Name';
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'just_use_my_email_name' );
```

Comment: That doesn't actually change where the emails come from. It's currently set to my email address and that doesn't appear anywhere in the password reset email.

Comment: @Rob check the edit i just made :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did a search around and solved it with: `function make_blog_name_from_name($name = '') {
     return get_bloginfo('name');
}
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'make_blog_name_from_name');`